# I want to know the name of this water plant?

Tags: species-identification, botany, limnology

[image]

Above is an image of an unknown plant. It grows without any care.

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE! Please have a look at [our policy for species identification questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) and edit your question accordingly. As it stands your question is unlikely to receive a definitive answer and it may be down-voted or deleted.

Comment: what country/pond/fields/woods/height of plant/flowers is it?

Comment: @com Size is clear from the picture and if there are no flowers, you can't take a picture of them. But I agree location and habitat (probably shore of a lake or ditch) should be mentioned.

Comment: I know this plant because it is very beautiful semi aquatic and it has yellow flowers in summer. This summer it was the most amazing plant that I found in the south of france cote d'azur rivers. I have just learned what it is. It has the most lustrious foliage of nearly any plant and it looks like green metal.

Comment: @com Yeah it is nice to look at. However, it is an invasive alien species that completely overgrows the river, blocking water from flowing and costing water management a lot of work and money. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is a water-primrose *Ludwigia*, probably *Ludwigia peploides* but I am not sure about the species (also because you didn't provide a location). *Luwigia peploides* and *L. grandiflora* are native to South america. However, in the rest of the world they are considered invasive weeds. [In the European union *L. peploides* and *L. grandiflora* are considered "Invasive alien species of Union concern"](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32016R1141) This means EU member states should take appropriate action against these species.

[image: picture from http://www.backyardnature.net/n/h/primwill.htm]
[image]

Water-primrose has a high variation in the shape of the leaves, especially between vegetative and flowering sprouts. On the picture in the question the leaves are almost round. However, on the ground just left of the hand, there are lanceolate leaves, almost willow-shaped. This is the same species and the reason it is also called floating primrose-willow.